# How to change color of unicode string in label on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, unicode

It is quite strange. If string consist of this unicode "" and although I set text color like this:

```objectivec
[self.lblText setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

I can't change color of "".  I can't use image and it has to be text. Is there any black color globe or how can I change those unicode text/symbol to a specific color?

Comment: Use `NSAttributedString` to set in label, follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287386/change-string-color-with-nsattributedstring or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231879/is-it-possible-to-change-color-of-single-word-in-uitextview-and-uitextfield

Comment: Does it relate with NSAttributedString ? I thought it is because of unicode.

Comment: I think you are using emoji as result you can't the colors of it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000876/how-would-i-change-the-color-of-a-emoji